# JavaScript - best way to collect information about a session

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, session, cookies

**CONTEXT**

I am building a Meteor web app that analyzes information about visits to a user's  website (think Google Analytics). The third party website will have a JS snippet that the user inserts and I would like to collect as much information as possible about each visit and then pass it back to my web app.

**PROBLEM**

I know that the typical way to do this would be with cookies but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of collecting and storing information about the visit. In particular:

1. What method would allow me to store the most data? I know that cookies typically have a 2-4KB limit, so that may be an issue.
2. What method would allow me to store the most types of information (e.g. pages visited, time spend on site, etc.).
3. What method would allow for the easiest transfer back to me web app?